# How to get last inserted row identity in a table of MS Access

Tags: c#, ms-access-2003

I need to know how to get last inserted row's identity in a table of MS Access

i am doing like:

in query at the end i have written this statement "Select @OutputId = SCOPE_IDENTITY()"

and in code i did

```
OLEDBParameter param = new OLEDBParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@OutputId";
param.Value = 0;
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

but i am getting this error:
"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter internal error: invalid parameter accessor:"

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: Please add more details like the whole function starting from opening the DB Connection to closing it.

Answer (score 3):

To select the last autonumber against a connection, you can use @@Identity.

```
 SELECT @@identity
```